# React TypeScript Conditional Rendering keep type guard in prop functions

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am conditionally rendering a Button. However, on line 7, the first parameter of the exportExcel function is the same variable that must be non-Nil for the Button to even render but TS is saying that `'data' is possibly null` on line 7. I feel that TS should know that it is not-Nil based on the conditional render but I also understand that the inline function is a new scope.

The only solution I found was optional chaining and `as any[]`. (first param of exportExcel is any[])

How do I make this TS error go away correctly?

`onClick={() => exportExcel(data?.productsByType?.products as any[], "program-data")}`

```
1.                {data.productsByType.products && (
2.                  <Button
3.                   color="primary"
4.                   variant="contained"
5.                   className="actionButton"
6.                   style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}
7.                   onClick={() => exportExcel(data.productsByType.products, "program-data")}
8.                 >
9.                   Download CSV
10.                 </Button>
11.               )}
```

Comment: There is no question here. Could you update this to make it clear what you are asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a call `exportExcel`, this is happening inside a callback. This callback is called at some point in the future and TypeScript can not make an assumption that the `data.productsByType` object has not changed in between you declaring the callback and it being called when user clicks on a button.

If you want to avoid that situation, you can save the value to a constant and then use that in your JSX code.

```js
const products = data.productsByType.products;
```

```js
{products && (
   <Button
     color="primary"
     variant="contained"
     className="actionButton"
     style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}
     onClick={() => exportExcel(products, "program-data")}
    >Download CSV</Button>
)}
```